# why my component doesn't work for inputs that given in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I am new to VHDL and I have an assignment about it. I have to make a register that can save the value of Y based on the value of the last 2 bits of X. But before that, there is a process to determine Y value to be used, based on a bit of "field", and this process is in the "initial" component. The "initial" component can work as expected but the "Regis" component, which has to save the value of Y, didn't work at all. And I don't know what's the problem, why my "Regis" component doesn't work as I expect. Would you help me to figure out the problem?

this is my top level module vhdl :

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
entity part1 is
Port ( X : in INTEGER;
       Y : in INTEGER;
       field : in STD_LOGIC;
       Z : out INTEGER);
end part1;

architecture Behavioral of part1 is
component initial
Port ( X : in INTEGER;
       Y : in INTEGER;
       FIELD : in STD_LOGIC;
       Y1 : out UNSIGNED(7 DOWNTO 0));
end component;

component regis
Port ( y : in INTEGER;
       x : in UNSIGNED(7 DOWNTO 0);
       yout : out INTEGER);
end component;

signal yi, xr : unsigned(7 downto 0);
signal yr, yo : integer;

begin

beginone : initial port map (X => X, Y => Y, FIELD => field, Y1 => yi);
xr <= to_unsigned (X, xr'length);
yr <= to_integer(unsigned(yi));
regY : regis port map (y => yr, x => xr, yout => yo); 
Z <= yo;

end Behavioral;
```

"initial" component listing :

```
signal xb, yb : unsigned(7 downto 0);

begin
xb <= to_unsigned(X, xb'length);
yb <= to_unsigned(Y, yb'length);
initial : process(FIELD, xb, by)
          variable ys : unsigned(7 downto 0);
          begin
            if (FIELD = '1') then
               ys := yb;
               else ys := xb xor yb;
            end if;
            Y1 <= ys;
          end process;
end Behavioral;
```

"regis" component listing :

```
begin
process(x(1), x(0))
     begin
       if (x(1) = '0' and x(0) = '0') then yout <= 0;
       elsif (x(1) = '0' and x(0) = '1') then yout <= y;
       elsif (x(1) = '1' and x(0) = '0') then yout <= 2*y;
       elsif (x(1) = '1' and x(0) = '1') then yout <= 3*y;
       else yout <= y;
       end if;
     end process;
end Behavioral;
```

and this is the testbench of the top level module :

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity part1_tb is
--  Port ( );
end part1_tb;

architecture Behavioral of part1_tb is
component part1
Port ( X : in INTEGER;
Y : in INTEGER;
field : in STD_LOGIC;
Z : out INTEGER);
end component;

signal x, y : integer;
signal field : std_logic;
signal z : integer;

begin
uut : part1 port map (x => X, y => Y, field => field, z => Z);
stim_proc : process
            begin
            wait for 100 ns;
            x <= 1;
            wait for 100 ns;
            y <= 2;
            wait for 100 ns;
            field <= '1';
            wait;
            end process;
end Behavioral;
```

if the program runs correctly, it will produce an output value of z = 2 according to the input being tested. but when the testbench simulated results z = 0.
Thanks all.

[image: testbench simulation]

Comment: The process in `regis` is missing `y` from the sensitivity list. For reference, you can use a string to compare all bits in a one liner, and you only need `x` in the sensitivity list, not both bits individually. `process(x,y) begin if x = "00" then`  etc

Comment: The context clauses and entity declarations are missing for initial and regis as is the **architecture** identifier **of** entity_name **is**. Your problem can't be replicated from the question as is. There's also a typo - `initial : process(FIELD, xb, yb)  -- yb WAS by`. This should be an error. There's also a bounds error when simulating. An integer negative default initial value is out of range for `to_unsigned (X, xr'length);`.